# Concatenate in ternary operator

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to concatenate a text and a value in angularjs. So far without luck.

```
<p class="duration">{{video.Duration > 0 ? "Test time-limit: " + {{video.Duration}} +  min." : "No time limit"}}</p>
```

Comment: Try this : `{{video.Duration > 0 ? ("Test time-limit: " + video.Duration +  "min.") : "No time limit"}}`

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? You had an error? The condition was not getting evaluated? The condition always evaluated wrong?

Comment: It is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix your statement:

```
{{video.Duration > 0 ? ("Test time-limit: " + video.Duration + " min.") : "No time limit"}}
```

You don't need the brackets when you are in a statement already.

Comment: Missed a `"`before `min`.

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p class="duration">{{video.Duration > 0 ? 'Test time-limit: ' + video.Duration.toString() + 'min. ' : 'No time limit'}}</p>
```